# How to save memory when many unordered_map<string, double>s have exactly the same string set as key

Tags: c++, string, memory, unordered-map

I am doing classification using features.

Each feature group is `unordered_map<string, double>`. `string` is the feature name and `double` is the feature value.

```
class FeatureGroup {
      private:
        unordered_map<string, double> features_ = unordered_map<string, double>{
                { "c_n_a", 0 },
                { "c_n_b", 0 },
                { "l_1_a_1mm", 0 },
                { "l_2_a_1mm", 0 },
                { "l_3_a_1mm", 0 },
                ...
            }
    }
```

Each instance has a feature group.
And, I have many (let's say 8000000) instances.

My problem is: I want to save memory without much effort. As you can say, I am already using short feature names.

Since the feature names for each instance is the same in an experiment, I don't want the feature name strings like "c_n_a", "c_n_b" be stored 8000000 times.

I have done some searching (such as using char* as Key type, std::reference_wrapper<>), but still confused. So, please help. What should I do to not store feature names 8000000 times and therefore save memory?

PS:

I read things about `flyweight` and found nothing that it should not work. However, after I changed the code as follows, my programm got dramatically slow.

```
using flyweight_string = boost::flyweight<std::string>;

class FeatureGroup {
    private:
        unordered_map<flyweight_string, double> features_ = unordered_map<flyweight_string, double>{
                { flyweight_string("c_n_a"), 0 },
                { flyweight_string("c_n_b"), 0 },
                { flyweight_string("l_1_a_1mm"), 0 },
                { flyweight_string("l_2_a_1mm"), 0 },
                { flyweight_string("l_3_a_1mm"), 0 },
                { flyweight_string("l_1_b_1mm"), 0 },
                ...
        }
}
```

When setting and getting the features, I use the following format:

```
features_[flyweight_string(feature_name)] // feature_name is of string type
```

When setting feature values I also used the following sentence to check whether the feature name is defined. If not, the program `exit(1)`.

```
if(features_.find(flyweight_string(feature_name)) != features_.end())
```

The structure of my program is as follows. I hope someone can find the reason why it get slow after the utilization of boost::flyweight.

In my program, each `Instance` (class) has an ID, `FeatureGroup`, and class label. I have another class called `InstanceManager`, which actually maintains a container of Instance (i.e. `unordered_set<Instance>`).
In my program, I calculate each feature for all instances, for example `"c_n_a"` for all instances at one time and then update the corresponding feature values stored in the containner. After all feature values have been calculated, I get the feature values of each intance and use an trained model to predict the class label.

The setting and getting of feature values of instances is parallized for the instance container using OpenMP.

In windows performance monitor, before the change to `boost::flyweight<std::string>`, all CPU cores was utilized at a level of almost 100%. After the change to flyweight, the CUP utilization declined to 6~7%. After all, my program get dramatically slower.

I don't know why parallelization didn't work properly because of the change from `string` to `flyweight_string`. And, how to fix it?

Comment: Use an array of strings to store the feature name and declare it as a constant.

Comment: Did you look into [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title. You can't have exactly the same string as a key in a map, unless it's a multimap, which isn't the case.

Comment: So your keys are always the same, but it's the values that change from instance to instance - is this the case ? Something like this : map<string, double> features_one = { {"key1":1 },{"key2":0.3 },{"key3":0.2 },{"key4":3 }} ; map<string, double> features_two = { {"key1":0.1 },{"key2":0.35 },{"key3":0.12 },{"key4":0.33 }} . Is that the case ?

Comment: @MiroRodozov , Exactly as you said, the keys are always the same, only the values changes from instance to instance. I chose to use unordered_map<string, double> rather than vector<double> to represent feature values because I wanted to save typing work and make the accessing of feature values more ituitively.

Comment: @rustyx Sorry, I couldn't figure out a better Enlish expression to express the real problem. I'm glad if you would give some good title to express the sutuation. I'm willing to change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can afford to hard code the names of the features into your source code.  If so, you shouldn't use strings at all - use an enum instead:

```
enum class FeatureName { c_n_a, c_n_b, l_1_a_1mm, l_2_a_1mm, l_3_a_1mm, ... };

class FeatureGroup {
      private:
        std::unordered_map<FeatureName, double> features_ =
            std::unordered_map<FeatureName, double> {
                { FeatureName::c_n_a, 0 },
                { FeatureName::c_n_b, 0 },
                { FeatureName::l_1_a_1mm, 0 },
                { FeatureName::l_2_a_1mm, 0 },
                { FeatureName::l_3_a_1mm, 0 },
                ...
            }
    }
```

You may need functions to convert between `FeatureName` and strings.  There are lots of examples of how to do that.  Note that the length of the enumerators has no impact on the memory consumption of the program, so you can afford to make them as long as you need for ease of reading.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who share their ideas. Ami Tavory's flyweight<> way doesn't work well with the OpenMP parallelization and I still haven't found the reason. Also, Ami Tavory's idea of using enum as the index of feature vector is cool. This technique should save a lot of RAM. However, after considering the amount of code modification, I choose Martin Bonner's way. Since the type of container doesn't change that much, I can save a lot of labor work.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

At the bottom is the original content of the answer, but following the update to the question, I'm completely revising it. You can modify your code to

```
class FeatureGroup {
  private:
    enum{
        c_n_a=0,
        c_n_b,
        ...
        num_features};
    std::vector<double> features_;
}
```

You should initialize `features` using `features(num_features)`. To access the feature corresponding to `c_n_b`, for example, just use `features_[c_n_b]`.

This is about as efficient as you can get. In fact, you do not need even to try to shorten the feature names.

---

The [flyweight design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) is explained by

> In computer programming, flyweight is a software design pattern. A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use by sharing as much data as possible with other similar objects; it is a way to use objects in large numbers when a simple repeated representation would use an unacceptable amount of memory.

It seems very easy here to use [`boost::flyweight`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/basics.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <boost/flyweight.hpp>

using fly_str = boost::flyweight<std::string>;

int main()
{   
    std::unordered_map<fly_str, int> m;
    m[fly_str("hello")] = 2;                                                                                                               
}
```

Comment: I tried boost::flyweight, but my program got very slow, can you help to find the reason? (See the part of PS in my post)

Comment: Also, I have a confusion. The short feature names I am using is so short that I wonder how much memory I can save through boost::flyweight<std::string>. Because although the hash values instead of real strings are stored, hash value is of 64-bit （My program is 64-bit windows program）.

Comment: I wonder if the using of flyweight<string> will make the threads wait for each other to read the background string. By the way, I'm using OpenMP. Because after the change to flyweight, the CUP utilization of each core becomes very very low (in total 6~7%).

Comment: @JohnSmith Your using OpenMP (which I think is a late edit to your question), indeed changes things possibly, due to cache lines. I'll look into it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediate look up that translated your string key to a number, which would then be stored as the key.

This function could have a vector where the string keys index in the vector would be the resulting number key. If the string key is not in the vector, insert it at the end, and return this keys index. The problem with this approach is that the lookup takes O(n). Alternatively you could store the number in a map, where they key is the string key.

Vector approach:

```
int StringKeyToNumber(vector<string>& lookup, const string& strKey) {
    auto it = find(begin(lookup), end(lookup), strKey);
    if (it != end(lookup)) {
        return distance(begin(lookup), it);
    }
    lookup.push_back(strKey);
    return look.size() - 1;
}
```

Map approach:

```
int StringKeyToNumber(map<string, int>& lookup, const string& strKey) {
    auto it = lookup.find(strKey);
    if (it != end(lookup)) {
        return it->second;
    }
    int newIndex = lookup.size();
    lookup[strKey] = newIndex;
    return newIndex;
}
```

I am not really sure that using `char*` as the key type, although it would lower the memory requirements, would be a good solution. It is easy to have two strings having the same content but at different memory locations.

Effectively you want a has value that you can assert is only representing one string representation, in this way you only need to store the hash value. The above solutions gives you that guarantee (at least for the first 2147483647 strings) :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the title says 'exactly the same string set as keys' you can first create single map :

```
map<string,int> myKeyToPositionMap = {
{ "c_n_a", 1 }, { "c_n_b", 2 },{ "l_1_a_1mm", 3 },{ "l_2_a_1mm", 4 },{ "l_3_a_1mm", 5 }};
```

and substitute the map in the FeatureGroup with a vector

```
class FeatureGroup {
      private:
vector<double> features_ = {0.2,0.1,0.3,0.5}; };
```

This way you got only one map from which you get the positions of the corresponding values in that vector, say you want to get the values for c_n_b,

```
int keyForCNB = myKeyToPositionMap.find("c_n_b");
double valueForCNB = featuresGroupInstance->getFeaturesVector.at(keyForCNB);
```